# How do you define a column based on a function of a unique subset for each row?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a column when working with time series data. The table has the following relevant columns: `t`, `i`, `j`, and `val`. What I want to do is create a column that is a distance weighted sum of `val`, based on observations with the same `i` & `t` values. If I use explicit values defined in variables (`test_t`,`test_i`,`test_j`) I can get a single column entry like so:

```
sum(data[t == test_t & i == test_i & j != test_j
                ][,dist:=sqrt((test_j - j)^2)
                  ][,adjustedVal:=val/dist
                    ][, adjustedVal])
```

How can I apply this over the entire data table? My first thought was to do something like this

```
data[,adjustedVal:=sum(data[i == i, j != j, t == t] #and so on like above
```

but obviously this has major issues with scoping. Is there a way to scope this so i can delineate between i(the column in data) and i(the value of column i in each row in this expression)?

Comment: Hello!  Kindly provide reproducible data using `dput(data)`, or something like `dput(head(data, 30))` if your `data` is very big.  Please also provide a sample of what you would want the output to be.  Also, is your `dist` supposed to be calculated from some aggregation over the entire vector of `j` values for that group?

Comment: You are much mure likely to get help if you provide a reproducible example with data. Read the comment by Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title, i think you are looking for

```
DT[, out :=
    DT[DT, on=.(t, i), by=.EACHI, 
        sum(i.val / abs(i.j - x.j[x.j != i.j]))
    ]$V1
]
```

sample data

```
DT <- data.table(t=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
    i=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
    j=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
    val=c(1,2,1,2,3,4,5))
```

output:

```
   t i j val       out
1: 1 1 1   1  1.500000
2: 1 1 2   2  4.000000
3: 1 1 3   1  1.500000
4: 2 2 4   2  3.666667
5: 2 2 5   3  7.500000
6: 2 2 6   4 10.000000
7: 2 2 7   5  9.166667
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! .EACHI appears to have been the missing piece here.